# How to write multiple else-if block with ng-if

Tags: c#, angularjs, html, if-statement

I have a block of `else-if` conditions in my `ASP.NET MVC Razor` page like this

```
if(ConditionSet1)
{  //Some HTML elements  }
else if(ConditionSet2)
{  //Some HTML elements  }
else if(ConditionSet3)
{  //Some HTML elements  }
else
{  //Some HTML elements  }
```

**What I tried:**

I tried this, which I thought should work, but it is not working. 
I used `ng-init` and set a model with name `elseClause`. Then I check if it for value != 1 (means previous div is not initiated).

```
<div ng-if="ConditionSet1" ng-init="elseClause = 1">
      <div> DIV-1 </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="ConditionSet2 && elseClause != 1" ng-init="elseClause = 1">
      <div> DIV-2 </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="ConditionSet3 && elseClause != 1" ng-init="elseClause = 1">
      <div> DIV-3 </div>
</div>

<!-- Else Block -->
<div ng-if="elseClause != 1">
      <div> DIV-4 </div>
</div>
```

It prints both `DIV-3` as well as `DIV-7`. 
It sets value 1 to elseClause but when it comes to second block, it doesn't carry that value.

Why is it happening?

Comment: It seems like you're coding business logic in the views. You should move this logic in the controller or some other service.

Comment: @Candide the above else-if blocks are created at run-time in foreach loop.

Comment: @Lali that's no excuse, you can prepare that array (add properties to individual objects) somewhere else before rendering them in the view, then your `ng-if` can check a single property.

Comment: you can create 1 function to do that, example: create function for if-else block http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/09/ng-class-if-example.html